# can't access recovery mode after flashing clockworkmod

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, recovery-mode

I flashed clockworkmod through adb and fastboot but after fastboot reboot my phone goes into boot stuck in the logo. after that I turned it off and go to bootloader recovery mode but after selecting recovery it just starts like normal and stops at logo
-I tried resetting my phone through fastboot and nothing happened.
-Tried flashing the recovery again still cannot access recovery mode
Note** fastboot is accessible when connected to pc

Comment: Please Help. I am really new to this and this is the first time it happened

Comment: Are you sure you flashed the right Clockworkmod image for your device?

Comment: yes i followed the rooting guide for my phone and it is exactly the mode and brand from the guide. right after flashing clockworkmod. it stucked on the logo. and when try to get to recovery mode via bootloader it just starts normally. Do I need to flash the whole stock rom?

Comment: What phone model do you have? What clockworkmod file did you flash? How?

Comment: its a very uncommon phone model firefly aurii secret lite.. tried to root via fastboot and succesfully unlocked bootloader.. after that i tried to flash cwm via fastboot through this link http://baabebiboobu.blogspot.com/2017/03/having-root-access-firefly-mobile-aurii.html?m=1 and boom. its stuck on the logo and wont boot.

Comment: Note: Rooting and unlocking bootloader are two different things. Not sure what's best. Did you try commenting on the website you mentioned?

Comment: Sorry.. I have flashed the stock rom and its back. it seems the recovery I flashed is really incompatible. Thanks.